# Any scientific evidence of "Breastfeeding Elimination Diet "?

Tags: diet, breastfeeding

Any scientific evidence of "Breastfeeding Elimination Diet " and the similar forms of diets recommended in mass media to deal with baby's "green poop" problem?

All official recommendations does not contain any references to such diet: http://www.euro.who.int/__data/assets/pdf_file/0020/120296/E73182.pdf?fbclid=IwAR1jw7o0cmUBAhrIARN0zcW5acMo4SKT-d_57uEcegb6elSMr1PuLdOm5zw

Or at least how could you explain what is an physiological idea behind? How the eaten "egg" could affect the mother's milk composition? It is absolutely not obvious.

Comment: What has your research revealed so far? Demonstrating some degree of prior research is required here.

Comment: I can't find any "evidence-based" reasearch - there is one which contains some interesting information: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5383635/?fbclid=IwAR38X_J-Nf2kTc4S03w0TEUF9CQcgClGI3k2w1XcWlaDGeJBK600aj8ZBRE but actually it has zero value, because authors are concentrated more on cultural restrictions in mother diet. They does not criticize diets that are claimed to solve "allergies".

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "green poop" problem, but I've answered the question re: whether maternal avoidance of certain allergens helps prevent the development of allergies in their children.

Answer (score 4):

Because food antigens both [cross the placenta](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=12569973) and are [excreted in breast milk](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=11277829), there was biological plausibility to the hypothesis that maternal avoidance of certain foods during both pregnancy and breastfeeding could impact the development of allergies in their children.  Initially the hypothesis was that avoidance would help prevent the development of allergies. **The data do not support that hypothesis**.

There is a good [Cochrane review](https://www.cochranelibrary.com/cdsr/doi/10.1002/14651858.CD000133.pub3/full) of the data, which concludes that there is no benefit, though they do note one trial with a non-significant trend toward decreased severity of eczema symptoms.  They reviewed trials of avoidance both during pregnancy and during lactation. Their conclusions:

> Prescription of an antigen avoidance diet to a high‐risk woman during pregnancy is unlikely to reduce substantially her child's risk of atopic diseases, and such a diet may adversely affect maternal or fetal nutrition, or both. Prescription of an antigen avoidance diet to a high‐risk woman during lactation may reduce her child's risk of developing atopic eczema, but better trials are needed.

I seem to recall an argument for the opposite intervention, but I can't seem to find the reference. As I recall, it was not very convincing either. Though initial exposure and sensitization are required for the development of allergic disease, the placenta and the breast are very particular immunologic environments. Personally, I would expect exposure at these sites would be more likely to induce tolerance than sensitization, but I don't believe the data support that either.